# C Programming - Static .a lib including program icon, is it possible?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, static, icons

I created a small C static library (.a) and an icon for it. Icon is compiled as resource, generating a icon.o file. I would like to embed this icon into my .a library, so, every time a program uses my library, it automatically has my icon.

At this moment the only solution to add the icon.o to the program is:

```
 gcc -o program.exe program.c icon.o mylib.a
```

but I would like to do it just this way:

```
 gcc -o program.exe program.c mylib.a
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If icon.o is inside mylib.a you've already done that :)
Otherwise just add it to the library, what's the problem with that?

Comment: @loreb If icon.o is inside mylib.a it doesn't work, program.exe icon is the default windows one.

Comment: The linker may not be including it in your code if it's not "used". As to how to *use* an icon in your code .. I have no idea. The problem goes away if you use a makefile, though (add it to your personal favourite `make` template).

Comment: @Ray doh, it looks like both me and Jongware misunderstood your question in exactly the same way :) try adding windows,winapi or some such tag to your question, and good luck

Comment: @loreb Thanks you both for answering. The point is that icon.o is compiled from a .rc file using winres and it basically contains the program icon (the icon for the .exe file). I was just wondering if it was possible to include this resource (the icon) in the .a library file. I googled a lot and I couldn't find the answer...

Comment: I mean, I can embed the compiled resource into .a but then, when compiling 'program' the icon does not appear.

Comment: @Ray got it, but the problem is that I'm not a windows programmer, so it didn't even occur to me that you wanted your executable to have an icon - I thought you were declaring the icon as an array of bytes and wanted it included, Jongware even wondered why you wanted to do that. That being said, my guts tell me it shouldn't be possible -- what if a program is using library A and library B, and **both** A and B want to do it? Your program should **request** an icon, and the fact that said icon is embedded in a library is just a detail (but notice that this is just my guess).

Comment: @loreb Thanks, what you say makes all the sense. Most probably, if icon in embedded in the library, it must be set by code to the exec. On the other way, linker automatically sets it. That's my guess...

Comment: You should probably tag this question gcc as it is specific to the GCC development tools.